# how can i import a folder containing images with python

Tags: python

i want to import a folder containing images from my local computer with python. How can i do that with python libraries.

Note: I want to import multiple images from a folder not only one image.

I want to Apply Machine Learning on that images .

Please help Me i am trying since 1 month but not find solution. I will be very Thankful to you.

Thanks in advance

I have tried Pillow library but its import only one image. And i want to import a folder full of images i.e 5k - 10k images from my local computer.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('/home/zain/Downloads/natural-image/natural_images/person*'):
    im=Image.open(f)
    image_list.append(im)
```

i don't know how to import a folder of images.
Please Help me. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to load images is using either a `for` loop or a simple Python list-comprehension

```
import os
from PIL import Image

input_dir = "/home/zain/Downloads/natural-image/natural_images/"

# load images one after another - useful for images one by one
for image in os.listdir(input_dir):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(input_dir, image))
    # do whatever you like to do with the img

# load all images data at in to list
image_list = [Image.open(os.path.join(input_dir, image)) for image in os.listdir(input_dir)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: Then please accept his answer, its how you thank him.

Comment: oh sorry i am newbie at stackoverflow. now i will accepted his answer